# Onclick listener inicias dos veces la actividad

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, programación-móvil

Tengo un problema y es que al presionar cualquier tipo de botón ya sea en un RecyclerView o en un botón normal si lo presionas múltiples veces la actividad navegación entre intents se produce el numero de veces que le hayas dado

Dejo fragmento de código aqui donde esta el Onclick del boton que lleva a otro intents y que si le doy dos veces lo abre dos veces:

```
HomeButton.setOnClickListener { view ->
            
            val intent = Intent(this, GamesActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Muchas Gracias de antemano

Comment: Si quieres cambiar el comportamiento en qué una actividad es lanzada debes cambiar la propiedad `android:launchMode` de la misma o agregar `ActivityFlags` al intent. Con esto puedes hacer que en vez de iniciar una Actividad nueva, la misma sea resumida, pero debes tener en cuenta el comportamiento del Stack de actividades, hay muchos ejemplos en la internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar esto puedes definir dentro del `AndroidManifest.xml` para tu Activity:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

esto para que solo se maneje siempre una instancia de la Activity.

ejemplo:

```
   <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

Revisa más información en :

[¿Cual es la diferencia entre android:launchMode="singleTask" y android:launchMode="singleInstance"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139786/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-androidlaunchmode-singletask-y-androidlaunchmod)

Answer (score 1):

A veces uno no quiere un single task.

La manera que evito esto es desactivando el bottom:

```
HomeButton.setOnClickListener { view ->

        view.isEnabled = false //desactivo

        val intent = Intent(this, GamesActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

        view.isEnabled = true //activo
        

        //otra forma mas segura de volver activar es con delay
         Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
              view.isEnabled = true
         },600) //milisegundos
    }
```